discover which package installed a Python script entry point?
tl;dr how do I discover which package installed a script entry point under Scripts directory?
Given a Python environment at path Python, it has a scripts entry points directory at Python/Scripts. For script Python/Scripts/foo.py, how do I discover which Python package installed foo.py?
Or in other words, how do I "reverse lookup" Python script entry points?

Not exactly what youa re looking for, but pip show has a verbose option which also outputs defined entry points and a -f option that lists installed files. You can probably build your own solution from there

You can list all files belonging to a given package with importlib.metadata.files(<package_name>). From there, writing a script in order to find what package a file belongs to is quite straigthforward:
import importlib.metadata

def find_file_pkg(file_path):
    for p in importlib.metadata.packages_distributions():
        try:
            for f in importlib.metadata.files(p):
                if file_path in str(f):
                    return p
        except importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError:
            pass
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(find_file_pkg('Scripts/foo.py'))

Edit/Note: it is usually recommended to set executables as EntryPoints. I first oversaw that your entry point is a .py file and proposed the below answer:
I'm not sure pip allows that but you can do it with python importlib.metadata.
First find out which module/function is launched by foo.exe with:
import importlib.metadata
importlib.metadata.entry_points().select(name='foo')

It will output something like:
[EntryPoint(name='foo', value='foo_module:foo_function', group='console_scripts')]

Then you get the package distribution with:
importlib.metadata.packages_distributions()['foo_module']

